# Highcharts tick date formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using a stacked bar chart as a very simple timeline. Each section of the timeline (green=on white=off) is defined in seconds. This means that the ticks also display in seconds.

[image: Timeline Example]
[Click here for bigger version](https://i1297.photobucket.com/albums/ag26/chiggerchug/timeline_zps1c738344.png~original)

Is there a way to define a starting date/time for the entire graph and use date/time instead of seconds along the x axis?

I've looked in the API documentation, and I found [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that gantt chart can be more "user-friedly" http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart

Comment: Cheers for the quick response, but on the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r6emu/) the chart doesn't render?

Comment: Ah no worries it was just an outdated reference to highcharts.js. [updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/1588/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use pointStart, and pointInterval:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval

You can also use pointRange to help fine tune the layout:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange

{{Edit : it seems I misunderstood your question and usage, and this answer doesn't quite apply.

I took your chart to be showing a vertical column chart where you wanted a datetime x axis.

so....nevermind :)